# trying to append a jar file in python unsuccessfully

Tags: python, jar, append

I'm trying to append a file to a .jar file using python but i keep hitting an error which states could not find main class: jar.

```
def add_to_jar():
    jarfile = "jarfile.jar"
    skin_image= Skin_Name.text() #this stores the full path to to file to be appended
    cmd = 'java jar uf ' + jarfile + " " + skin_image
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

any help appreciated

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the exact error message.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jar
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: jar.  Program will exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like an issue with the java interpretter's class path, which is typically defined as an environment variable.  Do you need to run `jar` through `java`?  Often `jar` is installed as a binary command by itself.  Does it work if you just change it to

```
cmd = 'jar uf ' + jarfile + " " + skin_image
```

Comment: I dont have to run it through java directly but if i use the code you suggested it just comes back with 'jar is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.